# how to generate a short unique id like imgur in python?

Tags: python, django

what algorithm is used to generate short unique id? for example 10 millions 7 characters id without collision. many website like "9gag.com", ifunny.co, bitly.com etc use short id for Uniform resource locator how to generate such id with few collision.

Comment: It's not just a single concept that goes into it; You can have 2 dB's, one which has all unused keys in it pre-populated, and the another one which has the keys currently in use

Answer (score 1):

You can try `secrets` module in python (>= 3.6)

```
import secrets
secrets.token_hex(nbytes=8)
secrets.token_urlsafe(nbytes=8)
...
```

I've also done the test, I haven't found any collision (but not guarantee there is no collision) for every few million generated tokens.

```py
def test_uniqueness(num_iter, fn, fn_kwargs):
     """
     would output list of tokens that collide,
     or empty list if no collision 
     """
     collisions = {}
     out = []
     for idx in range(num_iter):
         uid = fn(**fn_kwargs)
         if collisions.get(uid, None):
             out.append(uid)
         else:
             collisions[uid] = True
     return out

test_uniqueness(1000000, secrets.token_urlsafe, {'nbytes':8})
```